# Running hadoop jar in Amazon EMR

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-emr

I created a custom jar for a map-reduce app and tried running it in Amazon EMR job flow. I compiled the code in hadoop 1.0.4, however Amazon EMR has support for Hadoop 1.0.3. Also I compiled the code under jdk 1.7, and I am not sure which version of java does Amazon EMR use and where can we change that ?

Here is the stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/test/GWASMapReduce : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:180)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that Java 7 isn't supported by Amazon EMR. You'll need to try compiling your jar to to target an older JVM:

```
javac -target 1.6 -cp .... etc
```

Comment: I use java 7's new classes in my jar and the app will not work without them. That is really odd that Amazon does not support java 1.7. Thank you for your reply, Now I am sure that java 7 is not supported by Amazon EMR

Comment: Sorry, my comment was slightly wrong. I think it's the version of Hadoop that doesn't support Java 7.

Comment: Ohh ok. So Hadoop 1.0.4 does not support Java 7 and that is the reason I am getting this error. How about Amazon EMR, does it support all versions of Java ?

Comment: Actually, no I was right the first time. It's definitely EMR that doesn't support Java 7. You say that you're using Java 7 classes that aren't in Java 6. In this case, your life is going to get difficult. I'd have a look at moving to Java 6 or looking for a Java 7 backport for the classes.

Comment: Ok. So Amazon EMR does not support Java 7. I changed my classes to run on jre 6, but still ran into an issue. I changed my hadoop jars from 1.0.4 to 1.0.3 and it worked. Again thank you !

Comment: I know its quite a bit old but there's no need for switching to java 1.6 . Only changing to hadoop-core-1.0.3.jar along with picking the emr for 1.0.3 works.

Answer (score 0):

As per Muel Java 7 is not supported by Amazon EMR and as of today Amazon EMR supports version 1.0.3, 0.20.205.

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 is still not supported on the EMR platform, see [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=458701)

Answer (score 0):

Its now supported since a while. Minimum is AMI version 2.4. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/ami-versions-supported.html